# Work with landing pages outside org in Pardot

Tags: pardot

This seems to be a basic question but I'm unable to find an answer. Is it possible to A/B test landing pages outside a salesforce org with Pardot?

I checked this video resource http://www.pardot.com/training/landing-pages-35-building-using-custom-layout-template/ and it wasn't useful to find an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A/B Testing is for Email templates and not Landing Pages .

For testing Landing Pages in Pardot ,you have Multivariate test provided by the pardot .

Check this article on [Multivariate tests](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2126807-using-multivariate-tests)

> Multivariate tests are designed to measure the effectiveness of different landing pages over a period of time to determine the top performer.

Comment: Thanks, but should the pages for the test should be hosted on a salesforce org?

Comment: The pages can be on the pardot itself .You can create Landing pages in Pardot

Comment: Last question, how can I connect those pages to my site? Suppose I create 2 versions of a landing page with Pardot, how do I link it to my site which is hosted else where? Do they have a plugin or api for doing that?

Comment: @Lucia You will get a Vanity URL and a bitly URL from pardot which can be hosted on your site or vf .Thanks